# Can I defend with Amulet of Earth?

Tags: flesh-and-blood

The Amulet of Earth does not have any "shield" numbers on it. Can I defend with it, assuming that its defense value is 0? The question is in the context of Embodiment of Earth: it gives all the non-attack action cards +1 defense. So it can give meaning to defending with the Amulet of Earth.

[image]

[image]